# Is memcache for GAE client-side or server-side?

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached

I'm building an app which should also work offline (of course with stale data).

So I thought if the user is online, I'll query the datastore to fetch fresh data, and if he's online, I'll store the recently fetched data in memcache. But then I thought memcache in GAE is implemented on the server-side most probably. Am I right?

Edit: I made my browser work offline.Reloaded the page, nothing happened and nothing appeared in my logs. But then I disabled my laptop's WiFi and somehow it started working. I got `GET 200` requests in my log. Does this mean memcache is client-side?

Comment: Why is python tagged here?

Comment: Sorry about that. Deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. Memcache is server-side caching. It worked when I disabled the wifi on my laptop because my laptop ran the dev server and also hosted the memcache. When my browser was offline, it couldn't send out requests to anybody so it failed.